# Change Header name in nginx for basic auth or Aspnetcore for JWT

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, jwt

I am having a difficult issue. my problem is I am using asp.net core 2.0 website with jwt . When JWT passes token it has a header name as Authentication now I need to add HTTP Basic Auth of Nginx which also uses the same header. after login Nginx shows 403 as it overrides the header.

I need to change either JWT header or Nginx header whichever is possible.

Answer (score 1):

My issue has been resolved

You need to set override the OnMessageReceived event:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3728

Answer (score -1):

I solve with this in Startup.ConfigureServices

```
var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var header = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["custom-header"].ToString();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header) && header.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        context.Token = header.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

And in Startup.Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Comment: Explaining how your answer solves the problem will help others make use of your solution.  See [answer].